# SQL Server 2012 Write Return Values of Stored Procedure to Cells using Stored Procedure

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I wrote a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012 that takes three input values and returns a single result (a sum) after doing some calculations.

```
DECLARE @return_value int,
        @total numeric(20, 2)

EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[storedprocedure]
                        @input1 = 'input_value',
                        @input2= 12345,
                        @input3 = 5

SELECT @total as '@total'

SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value
```

This returns a value, e.g.

```
@total 1000,02  --this is the correct value which I want to use--
```

and

```
Return Value 1000
```

I have a table with values in some columns that I want to act as inputs and an empty column, into which I want to fill the results from the @total variable of my stored procedure.

If I am not much mistaken, then need a second stored procedure which executes the first one cycling through all rows, and writing the values into them.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what's inside the stored procedure but, probably, you can create a function instead. Like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[YourFunctionName]
(
     @input1 VARCHAR(10)
    ,@input2 INT
    ,@input3 INT
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    -- Your code here.

    RETURN -- You return value here.
END
```

And use it like this:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET YourColumn = dbo.YourFunctionName(Input1, Input2, Input3)
```

Otherwise you must declare a cursor, execute the stored procedure and perform the update for each row. Iterative approaches are not recommended for several reasons, but that's beyond the scope of this question I guess.